# Duplicates counting with order order preserving in Python lists

Tags: python, list, no-duplicates

suppose the list

> [7,7,7,7,3,1,5,5,1,4]

I would like to remove duplicates and get them counted while preserving the order of the list. To preserve the order of the list removing duplicates i use the function

```
def unique(seq, idfun=None):
   # order preserving
   if idfun is None:
       def idfun(x): return x
   seen = {}
   result = []
   for item in seq:
       marker = idfun(item)
       if marker in seen: continue
       seen[marker] = 1
       result.append(item)
   return result
```

that is giving to me the output

> [7,3,1,5,1,4]

but the desired output i want would be (in the final list could exists) is:

> [7,3,3,1,5,2,4]

7 is written because it's the first item in the list, then the following is checked if it's the different from the previous. If the answer is yes count the occurrences of the same item until a new one is found. Then repeat the procedure. Anyone more skilled than me that could give me a hint in order to get the desired output listed above? Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you mean `7,4`

Comment: Are you sure your desired output list is correct? Like if there is only one value, leave off the quantity?

Comment: I'd like to to thank everybody who spent time answering, now i have better clues about lists and dictionaries. Actually the code in the answer outputs what i want: [7,4,3,1,5,2,1,4] but also the other answers in a way did solve my problem.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3782691 Next time think about the output clearly before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import collections as c
lst = [7,7,7,7,3,1,5,5,1,4]
result = c.OrderedDict()
for el in lst:
    if el not in result.keys():
        result[el] = 1
    else:
        result[el] = result[el] + 1

print result
```

prints out: `OrderedDict([(7, 4), (3, 1), (1, 2), (5, 2), (4, 1)])`

It gives a dictionary though. For a list, use:

```
lstresult = []
for el in result:
    # print k, v
    lstresult.append(el)
    if result[el] > 1:
        lstresult.append(result[el] - 1)
```

It doesn't match your desired output but your desired output also seems like kind of a mangling of what is trying to be represented

Comment: `.keys()` is unnecessary and in Python 2 will load a list into memory and make the `in` check O(N) instead of O(1). `el not in result` works fine

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> seen = set()
>>> out = []
>>> for k, g in groupby(lst):
    if k not in seen:
        length = sum(1 for _ in g)
        if length > 1:
            out.extend([k, length])
        else:
            out.append(k)
        seen.add(k)
...         
>>> out
[7, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
```

**Update:**

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989004/duplicates-counting-with-order-order-preserving-in-python-lists#comment44370197_27989004) I guess you wanted something like this:

```
>>> out = []
>>> for k, g in groupby(lst):
    length = sum(1 for _ in g)
    if length > 1:
        out.extend([k, length])
    else:
        out.append(k)
...         
>>> out
[7, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4]
```

Comment: true it is, its a weird structure for a list (I don't know what OP uses it for) though but this does solve it